# css - Adding a class to all section elements

Tags: html, css

I want to add the 'foo' class to all **section** elements on a page.  I understand that I could simply:

```
<section class="foo">...</section>
```

on every **section** element, but there are **many** sections.  Is there an easier way to do this?  (note: foo is a 3rd party class).

I also realise that I could style it like this:

```
section { font-style:...; color:...; /* all foo class styles */ }
```

but then I am duplicating the 'foo' class, which is against my principles.  If the 'foo' class changes I want my sections to change 'automatically' in the same way, without me having to edit my duplicate style.

Comment: Your 2 options are to either add it to each section class (seriously you've already typed them so just do it) or use some js on page load and apply the class using a query selector.

Comment: why not jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The only limitation you're facing is to identificate which **elements you want to style**. These identificators are called [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and you need to specify which are on your stylesheet in order to give them a style.

If you can identify in some certain way all of your elements that you want to style, then you have your selector.

With your selector defined, you can define the css specifications in your .css

You're able to specify one style for one or multiple selectors, and maybe this is what you're looking for, just do this:

```
.foo, section {
  font-style:...;
  color:...;
  /* all foo class styles */
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the mechanical component of adding a class to your many `section` elements, depending on your text editor you may be able to find & replace across documents. I believe [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) offers such a feature.

It would look something like:

```
find: <section>
and replace with: <section class="foo">
```

Of course, you may not have uniformly styled or classed `section` elements. In which case you may be able to hack it with something like:

```
find: <section class="
and replace with <section class="foo 
*note the space after foo
```

Not the most elegant solution, but in some cases it certainly works :)

Answer (score 0):

An idea that helps me usually is if you want it to keep it within the span of a page. I'd give the body a class name and do body.classname section and apply whatever class i want considering they will all have it.

```
    <body class = "page_identifier">
      <section></section>

      <section></section>

      <section></section>



      <section></section>
      <section></section>


      <section></section>

      ...etc


</body>

// Styles //
     body.page_identifier section{
          /*ENTER STYLES HERE */
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.   I was hoping there was some way of doing it in a style sheet, but I guess a global search/replace will have to do.  No big deal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good options that were already suggested, I think Nicolas's is the best. If you're using `Sass` for example, you can extend the section style:

```
section {
    @extend .foo;
}
```

You can read more about Sass [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Answer (score 0):

### Please Try

```css
section.foo p {
  color: pink;

}
```

```html
<section class="foo">


<p>Hello World!</p>


</section>
```

This will allow you to call the class *.foo*, change the color of the *p* element to pink. Only in that section.